# PDF file font is different on different downloads

Tags: php, apache, pdf, fonts

I know this question might seem vague, but I will try my best.  I have 1 file server with some PDF files stored on the file server.  ( Not sure if this is important but the PDF files were created with **wkhtmltopdf**. )

The problem is that, depending on which server initiates a download of the file, the PDF font is different.  The strangest thing is that I gave the file server a public URL, and accessed the files directly by redirecting to the URL of the file.  And the fonts are still different depending which server redirects to the file.

I have 4 different web servers, all Ubuntu 16.04 Apache Servers all running PHP 7.0.

So when the development server initiates the download ( or redirect ), the font of the PDF is correct, as should be expected: Courier.  When the staging server initiates the download, the font shows up as something else.  Inspecting the PDF file confirms the fonts are different.

Here is the download code:

```
<?php

$filename = $_GET['filename'];
$file = '/storage/webfiles/Customer Service/Invoice/'.$filename;

header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');

@readfile($file);
```

Somehow even though all web servers are accessing the same file, when it is loaded to the client the font encoding becomes different.  I really have no idea what to do.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like discrepancy of installed fonts on the server.

Comment: Like Jon said, test your servers and look if they have Courier installed. But you may want to look your PDF generator too. Usually, fonts are embedded with the PDF file so it looks exactly the same no matter which computer or OS you're in. What might be happening is that your fonts are not being embedded or simply your system does not support this kind of font (which is not likely because you are using 4 systems with the same OS.)

Comment: Are these PDF files being generated "on the fly"?

Comment: @JonStirling  bingo.  I had to install `msttcorefonts` using `apt-get install` and then `sudo fc-cache -f -v` to get it to work.  This was the issue.

Comment: @RamRaider No they are not being created on the fly, they are just sitting on the server.  But they were originally created with `wkhtmltopdf`.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind Good times :D